# javascript obtain get params server side

Tags: javascript

I have the following call:

```
      $http.get(
    '../api/hello', {
      params: {
        hello: "world"
      }
    }).then(function (res) {
      //do response
    })
```

and the following route:

```
    server.route({
    path: '/api/hello',
    method: 'GET',
    handler(req, reply) {
        //get hello
    }

})
```

I'm trying to get the parameter called 'hello' on the '//get hello'. I have tried to use 'req.params' but it returns {}.

Is there something wrong with the call or how can i get the hello parameter?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I would suggest inspecting your requests in the network tab of your browser devtools to make sure that your parameters are being sent to the server. you can check this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference) for refference

Answer (score -1):

Form look of it, you are using express, aren't you?

Try:

```
server.route({
    path: '/api/hello',
    method: 'GET',
    handler(req, reply) {
        let hello = req.query.hello; // here
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm using nodejs but your answer works.Thanks

Comment: Express is HTTP server for Node.js...